# Java Resource Leak

Tags: java, fileinputstream, resource-leak

I have this code snippet in my application and I am quite sure that I have 
closed all the streams.

But, surprisingly, I keep getting:
A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called

Any pointers would be very useful.

```
if (fd != null) {
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fd.getFileDescriptor());
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fileStream.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        content = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {

            if (fileStream != null) {
                fileStream.close();
            }

            if (bos != null) {
                bos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed adding the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

try moving the instantiation of the streams into the `try`

```
InputStream fileStream = null;
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
try {

  fileStream = new FileInputStream(fd.getFileDescriptor());
  bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

Comment: I guess it would even better if you use try with resources , which implements the AutoCloseable. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html. Ofcourse only if you are using Java 7 or above.

Answer (score 1):

Try using try with resources. This eliminates the need to close resources in a finally block. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

```
if (fd != null) {
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    try (InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(fd.getFileDescriptor());
         ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fileStream.read(buf)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
        }
        content = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using try with resources would resolve the issue. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html. You can have a look at AutoCloseable interface here which has been introduced in Java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html

Answer (score 0):

What I see, is that bos won't be closed if an Exception occurres while closing the fileStream.

And as stated before: Use the  try-with-resources Statement:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html